# How can i make my Cycles Cloth Shader to look Translucent

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

Hey i Created this Shader which i think really gives good results on cloth but i want to have a bit translucency in it but cant figure out the best way somethign with SSS maybe ? I dont know. You can Improve my Shader or give an even better Shader as Answer if you want.

PS: I figured out best way is with SSS just need to figure out the correct settings

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: like the guy said himself that that isnt a very realistic option and he didnt wanted to go straight forward and it would be better to use SSS.But i want to go that much straight forward and lean myself out of the windows that i fall out of it :D some Good SSS settings would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think with some tweaking, you could get this flag material to look better using a glossy or a velvet shader:

[image]

The idea was to recreate the actual threads and have the space in between them be transparent.

[image]